# Using Multiple 'OR' statements in Google Sheets 'IF' formula with a Continuous Range with #ERROR

Tags: google-sheets

I am working with a data set of ~7k rows in Google Sheets, but only 8 columns (A:H). I am trying to use an IF formula on a continuous range in Column B that checks several possible OR values from Column B that then returns a 'Yes' or 'No' value for each row in Column H. I keep getting a Formula Parse Error, but can't figure out where the problem is.

See below for my current formula that's not working. Thanks in advance for any ideas and suggestions.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(OR(B5:B="AB Special Use 1 - Standard",
        B5:B="AB Special Use 2",
        B5:B="Design District Review",
        B5:B="Incremental Review",
        B5:B="Infrastructure Construction",
        B5:B="Infrastructure Construction Substantial Change",
        B5:B="Rezoning",
        B5:B="Special Use 2"
        B5:B="Substantial Change",
        B5:B="Substantial Change - Site Plan Zoning",
        B5:B="Substantial Change - Special Use"),
                "Yes", "No"))
```

Comment: "Carlos M" below has offered a solution. However, in looking at your formula, I can't help but feel that there is probably a more concise way of going about this. However, I'd need to know the entire list of possible options that might appear in Column B. If you'd like to share a link to the sheet (or a copy of it) and indicate the entire list somehow, I may be able to condense this formula for you. Just be sure to set the link's Share permission (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

The `OR` function does not work inside `ARRAYFORMULA`, but you can emulate the function using boolean addition.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF((B5:B="AB Special Use 1 - Standard")
        +(B5:B="AB Special Use 2")
        +(B5:B="Design District Review")
        +(B5:B="Incremental Review")
        +(B5:B="Infrastructure Construction")
        +(B5:B="Infrastructure Construction Substantial Change")
        +(B5:B="Rezoning")
        +(B5:B="Special Use 2")
        +(B5:B="Substantial Change")
        +(B5:B="Substantial Change - Site Plan Zoning")
        +(B5:B="Substantial Change - Special Use"),
                "Yes", "No"))
```